# Sync Framework: Filtering multiple rows

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have the following code I am trying to allow users to choose multiple items to sync:

```
serverTemplate.Tables["dbo.order_details"].AddFilterColumn("order_id");

serverTemplate.Tables["dbo.order_details"].FilterClause = 
String.Format("[side].[order_id] IN ({0})", "@order_ids");

var param2 = new SqlParameter("@order_ids", SqlDbType.Structured);

serverTemplate.Tables["dbo.order_details"].FilterParameters.Add(param2);

serverTemplate.Apply();
```

I need a way to filter on multiple "order_ids".  The examples I see for Sync Framework filtering only filters on one ID.  I thought I could use `SqlDbType.Structured`data type to show that "order_ids will be a list.  However, I get the following error on : `serverTemplate.Apply();`

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled
  Message=Column, parameter, or variable #5: Cannot find data type READONLY.
Parameter or variable '@order_ids' has an invalid data type.
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions for this problem:

- You could either make `order_ids` a `DataTable` which is what would be accepted by a param of type `SqlDbType.Structured` (see fo an example http://s.codeproject.com/KB/database/TableValuedParameters.aspx and http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-and-c-custom-iterators-a-match-made-in-heaven/)

OR

- You could formulate this as a subselect on some table which you use to store the IDs one per row.

Comment: @BladeHal that won' work - follow the links in my answer... you need to make a `DataTable` from that `List<int>`...